# How do I Spy or Mock an Angular @Input in Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a component which has an Input, and functions that use the inputs

Component:

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
....

showPreviousEmployer() {
    return parseInt(this.form.value.yearsWithEmployer, 10) < 5;
}
```

How Can I either Spy on or mock 'form' for jasmine tests?

I tried:

```
    spy = spyOnProperty(component, 'form', 'get').and.returnValue({value: {yearsWithEmployer: '6'}});
    expect(component.showPreviousEmployer).toBe(false);
```

However that gives the error:

> Error: form property does not exist

Answer (score 5):

Apparently I can set the value directly without a spy or mock:

```
   component.form = {value: {yearsWithEmployer: '6'}};
   expect(component.showPreviousEmployer()).toBe(false);
```